# How to change listview selected row backcolor even when focus on another control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, focus, backcolor

I have a program which uses a barcode scanner as input device so that means I need to keep the focus on a text box.

The program has a listview control and I select one of the items programatically when a certain barcode is scanned. I set the background color of the row by:

```
listviewitem.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
```

Things I have tried:

- `listview.HideSelection` set to false
- call `listview.Focus()` after setting the color
- `listviewitem.Focused` set to true
- call `listview.Invalidate`
- call `listview.Update()`
- call `listview.Refresh()`
- different combinations of the above

I've also did combinations above stuff in a timer so that they are called on a different thread but still no success.

Any ideas?

More info:

- The key here is the control focus. The **listview control does not have the focus** when I select one of the items.
- I select one item by doing:

  ```
  listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
  ```
- the Focus is always in the textbox.
- the computer does not have keyboard or mouse, only a barcode reader.

I have this code to keep the focus on the textbox:

```
private void txtBarcode_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.txtBarcode.Focus();
}
```

You need to have a textbox add that code to simulate my problem.

Comment: Cant understand the problem. Code `listView1.Items[0].BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;` works well. What are you trying to achive but cant?

Comment: My *guess* is that the default Windows selection highlight is overriding your custom background color. It's really impossible to say; your question is very unclear as to what the actual problem is.

Comment: I've hilighted the main key in the problem. Thanks guys for looking at my question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**What you describe works *exactly* as expected**, assuming that you've set the `HideSelection` property of the `ListView` control to False. Here's a screenshot for demonstration purposes. I created a blank project, added a `ListView` control and a `TextBox` control to a form, added some sample items to the `ListView`, set its view to "Details" (although this works in any view), and set `HideSelection` to false. I handled the `TextBox.Leave` event just as you showed in the question, and added some simple logic to select the corresponding `ListViewItem` whenever its name was entered into the `TextBox`. **Notice that "Test Item Six" is selected in the `ListView`:**

[image: Screenshot of test project — note that "Test Item Six" is highlighted, even though the ListView control does not have the focus.]

Now, as I suspected initially, **you're going to mess things up if you go monkeying around with setting the `BackColor` property yourself**. I'm not sure why you would ever want to do this, as the control already uses the default selection colors to indicate selected items by default. If you want to use *different* colors, you should change your Windows theme, rather than trying to write code to do it.

In fact, if I add the line `item.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue` in addition to my existing code to select the `ListViewItem` corresponding to the name typed into the `TextBox`, I get *exactly* the same thing as shown above. The background color of the item doesn't change until you set focus to the control. That's the *expected* behavior, as selected items look different when they have the focus than they do when their parent control is unfocused. Selected items on focused controls are painted with the system highlight color; selected items on unfocused controls are painted with the system 3D color. Otherwise, it would be impossible to tell whether or not the `ListView` control had the focus. Moreover, any custom `BackColor` property is *completely ignored* by the operating system when the `ListView` control has the focus. The background gets painted in the default system highlight color.

Explicitly setting the focus to the `ListView` control, of course, causes the custom background color to be applied to the `ListViewItem`, and things render with a color that very much contrasts with the color scheme that I've selected on my computer (remember, not everyone uses the defaults). The problem, though, becomes immediately obvious: **you can't set the focus to the `ListView` control because of the code you've written in the `TextBox.Leave` event handler method!**

I can tell you right now that setting the focus in a focus-changing event is the wrong thing to do. It's a hard rule in Windows you're not allowed to do things like that, and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) even warns you *explicitly* not to do it. Presumably, your answer will be something along the lines of "I have to", but that's no excuse. If everything were working as expected, you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.

So, what now? **Your application's design is broken. I suggest fixing it.** Don't try and monkey with setting the `BackColor` property yourself to indicate that an item is selected. It conflicts with the default way that Windows highlights selected items. Also, don't try and set the focus in a focus-changing event. Windows explicitly forbids this, and the documentation is clear that you're not supposed to do this. If the target computer doesn't have a mouse or keyboard, it's unclear how the user is going to set focus to anything else in the first place, unless you write code to do it, which you shouldn't be doing.

But I have surprisingly little faith that you'll want to fix your application. People who ignore warnings in the documentation tend to be the same people who don't listen to well-meaning advice on Q&A sites. So I'll throw you a bone and tell you how to get the effect you desire anyway. **The key lies in not setting the `ListViewItem`'s `Selected` property, which avoids the conflict between your custom `BackColor` and the system default highlight color.** It also frees you from having to explicitly set the focus to the `ListView` control and back again (which, as we established above, isn't actually happening, given your `Leave` event handler method). Doing that produces the following result:

[image: Fixed sample — notice the ugly blue color of the "selected" item contrasting with my current theme settings.]

And here's the code—it's not very pretty, but this is just a proof of concept, not a sample of best practice:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      listView1.View = View.Details;
      listView1.HideSelection = false;
   }

   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
      {
         if (item.Text == textBox1.Text)
         {
            item.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            return;
         }
      }
   }

   private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      this.textBox1.Focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow - you're a bit scathing in parts here! But overall it's a good answer ;)

Comment: @Vidar: Hmm, upon reflection, you're right. I'm not sure why I was so frustrated here. Perhaps there was an extended exchange in the comment thread that has now been deleted. Or I was just in a bad mood. I'm not always such a grump! But a frustrating amount of applications *do* get this wrong...

Comment: Thank you! Been fighting with this for a couple hours this morning.

Comment: Thinking outside the box.

Comment: Along the lines of Vidar's comment... I'm probably not the only person who ended up here because I wanted to force ListBox and ListView to behave the same. Out of the box the mismatched styling is confusing for users.

Comment: Anyone who is trying to apply custom colors to standard Windows controls is doing it wrong. It is not unexpected that things will break. I wish application developers would stop doing this. Users hate it, too. We don't want our apps to look garish and different.

Answer (score 24):

A standard `ListView` does not let you set the background color of a *selected* row. The background (and foreground) colors of a selected row are always controlled by the theme of the OS.

You have to owner draw your `ListView` to get around this OR you can use [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx). ObjectListView is an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView, which makes it **much** easier to use, as well as easily allowing things that are very difficult in a normal ListView -- like changed the colors of selected rows.

```
this.objectListView1.UseCustomSelectionColors = true;
this.objectListView1.HighlightBackgroundColor = Color.Lime;
this.objectListView1.UnfocusedHighlightBackgroundColor = Color.Lime;
```

This shows the ObjectListView when it does **not** have focus.

[image]

Comment: great idea, but take note that it doesn't work for the "List" View mode; you have to switch over to "Details" View mode

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution for a ListView that does not allow multiple selections and
does not have images (e.g. checkboxes).

1. Set event handlers for the ListView (in this example it's named *listView1*):

   - DrawItem
   - Leave   (invoked when the ListView's focus is lost)
2. Declare a global int variable (i.e. a member of the Form that contains the ListView,
   in this example it's named *gListView1LostFocusItem*) and assign it the value -1

   - int gListView1LostFocusItem = -1;
3. Implement the event handlers as follows:

   ```
   private void listView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Set the global int variable (gListView1LostFocusItem) to
       // the index of the selected item that just lost focus
       gListView1LostFocusItem = listView1.FocusedItem.Index;
   }

   private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
   {
       // If this item is the selected item
       if (e.Item.Selected)
       {
           // If the selected item just lost the focus
           if (gListView1LostFocusItem == e.Item.Index)
           {
               // Set the colors to whatever you want (I would suggest
               // something less intense than the colors used for the
               // selected item when it has focus)
               e.Item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
               e.Item.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

              // Indicate that this action does not need to be performed
              // again (until the next time the selected item loses focus)
               gListView1LostFocusItem = -1;
           }
           else if (listView1.Focused)  // If the selected item has focus
           {
               // Set the colors to the normal colors for a selected item
               e.Item.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
               e.Item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           // Set the normal colors for items that are not selected
           e.Item.ForeColor = listView1.ForeColor;
           e.Item.BackColor = listView1.BackColor;
       }

       e.DrawBackground();
       e.DrawText();
   }
   ```

Note: This solution will result in some flicker.  A fix for this  involves subclassing the ListView control so you 
can change the protected property *DoubleBuffered* to true.

```
public class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    public ListViewEx() : base()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: A control or form shouldn't have to listen to their own events.  Just override OnDrawItem, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Easy to make it work with multiple selection. However, a clean solution to make it work with multiple columns (sub-items) remains unclear.

Answer (score 2):

In Details mode, ListView will keep selected item(s) highlighted after ListView looses focus exactly as ListBox does. Make sure HideSelection is TRUE and simply use this code:

```
private void ListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    
    foreach (ListViewItem it in (sender as ListView).Items)
    {
        if (it.Selected && it.BackColor != SystemColors.Highlight)
        {
            it.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            it.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        }
        if (!it.Selected && it.BackColor != SystemColors.Window)
        {
            it.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            it.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
    private void lBxDostepneOpcje_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListViewItem item = lBxDostepneOpcje.FocusedItem as ListViewItem;
        ListView.SelectedIndexCollection lista = lBxDostepneOpcje.SelectedIndices;
        foreach (Int32 i in lista)
        {
            lBxDostepneOpcje.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Selected = false;
            if (item.Index == 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                lBxDostepneOpcje.Items[item.Index-1].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            if (lBxDostepneOpcje.Items[item.Index].Focused == true)
            {
                lBxDostepneOpcje.Items[item.Index].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                if (item.Index < lBxDostepneOpcje.Items.Count-1)
                {
                    lBxDostepneOpcje.Items[item.Index + 1].BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
            else if (lBxDostepneOpcje.Items[item.Index].Focused == false)
            {
                lBxDostepneOpcje.Items[item.Index].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant set focus on listview control in this situation. `txtBarcode_Leave` method will prevent this. But if you are desire to be able select listview items by clicking on them, just add code below to `MouseClick` event handler of listview:

```
    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView list = sender as ListView;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list.Items[i].Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
            {
                list.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Blue; // highlighted item
            }
            else
            {
                list.Items[i].BackColor = SystemColors.Window; // normal item
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Anton, unfortunately there is no mouse or keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Just do like this:

1. Set property UnfocusedHighlighForegroundColor = "Blue"
2. Set property UnfocusedHighlighBackgroundColor = "White"
3. Set property UserCustomSelectionColors = true

Good luck :)