# How to set "background" color of selected item in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

how can I set or change "background color" of selected item in objestlistview? Basically, how I can get rid of the blue color in the background of text?

[image]

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179664/how-to-change-listview-selected-row-backcolor-even-when-focus-on-another-control) is going to solve explicitly your problem.

Comment: @siadynamic: No, he is talking about a custom control *ObjectListView*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the picture you use translucent selections:

```
objectListView1.UseTranslucentSelection = true;
```

You also have to set

```
objectListView1.OwnerDraw = true;
```

to get rid of the dark blue selection color.